# Test if input is a string instead of a number?

Tags: python, input

Sorry I'm a beginner. But like if I had:

```
x = eval(input('Enter a value for x: '))
```

How do I make it so that if the person input a string instead of a number it would print `"Enter a number"` instead of getting an error. Some type of if statement where:

```
if x == str():
    print('Please enter a number')

else:
    print('blah blah blah')
```

Comment: better close targets would have been: [How do I check if a string is a number in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python) or
[How do you check if a string contains ONLY numbers - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388541/how-do-you-check-if-a-string-contains-only-numbers-python)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> x = input(':')
:abcd
>>> x.isdigit()  # Returns False because x contains non-digit characters
False
>>> x= input(':')
:123
>>> x.isdigit()  # Returns True because x contains only digits
True
>>>
```

In your code, it would be:

```
if not x.isdigit():
    print('Please enter a number')  
else:
    print('blah blah blah')
```

---

On a side note, you should avoid using `eval(input(...))` because it can be used to execute arbitrary expressions.  In other words, it is very often a security hole and is therefore considered a bad practice by most Python programmers. Reference:

[Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)