# Use try catch statement for empty input

Tags: exception, python-3.x, integer, try-catch

I was attempting to distinguish an empty input from others using the try catch statement. Currently, I have this.

```
while True:
    try:
        user = int(input("Please enter an integer"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Must be an integer")
```

The problem comes from the fact that I would like a separate error statement if the user does not enter anything and only presses the enter key. However, it still reads that particular input as a ValueError and gives the me the message above no matter what else I try.

Comment: You could just check the input before passing to int.  If you want a one-liner, you could also do: int(input("Please enter an integer") + 1/0).  That will raise ZeroDivisionError if empty string.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a little new to this. How would I check the input before I pass it to int?

Comment: value = input("Please enter an integer"); if value: user = int(value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if the [string is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python).

```
while True:
    try:
        s = input("Please enter an integer")
        if not s:
             print ("Input must not be empty")
        elif not s.isdigit():
             print ("Input must be a digit")
        else:
            user = int(s)
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Must be an integer")
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like that works. Though if you don't mind, I had a related question. What if you wanted the user to enter a string such as a letter and have the program return an error if the user entered an integer?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388541/how-do-you-check-if-a-string-contains-only-numbers-python I updated my answer. If this answers your question, please mark my answer as accepted.