# Python2, checking if a string contains only numbers, confusion with x.isdigit()

Tags: python, string

Having looked at [How do you check in python whether a string contains only numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388541/how-do-you-check-in-python-whether-a-string-contains-only-numbers) , I am aware that string.isdigit() is an effective way to test if a string contains only digits and nothing else.  I am using Python 2.7.

However, when I try to use it in the following code, my program crashes with an "invalid literal for int() with base 10" error when I input any mix of numbers and non-numbers, e.g. "fsd7sfd" or similar.  (The code works fine with either number-only strings or alpha-only strings.)

I don't understand how this is happening, since as far as I can tell, the assignment of "how_much = int(choice)" should never happen **unless** the string only contains digits in the first place, when choice.isdigit() is True.

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

As a side note, that "print "test"" line doesn't seem to get processed before the error either, which adds to my confusion.

(I'm trying to improve the "gold_room()" function from https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html , the rest of the code is there for reference.)

Error:

```
This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?
> sdfgsd8sd 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex35.py", line 79, in <module>
start()
File "ex35.py", line 71, in start
bear_room()
File "ex35.py", line 36, in bear_room
gold_room()
File "ex35.py", line 9, in gold_room
how_much = int(choice)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sdfgsd8sd'
```

Code:

```
def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    print "test" 

    if choice.isdigit() == False:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    else:
        how_much = int(choice)


    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)

    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

Comment: This code does not run. If I add the missing `:`s, it gives me the expected 'dead' message when I type "fsd7sds".

Comment: This code works fine for me with the addition of those colons. And since `choice.isdigit()` returns a boolean: your `else` will never run.

Comment: Thanks AShelly, you are right, I did forget my colons.  That said, this code actually does run without them, surprisingly enough, and gives the same behavior once I add them in.  =\

Comment: Your environment is wrong then... how are you running it? have you overwritten `isdigit()`? This [repl.it](https://repl.it/HKEt/0) shows it works

Comment: TemporalWolf: I actually just realized you are right.  I was running a previous version of the wrong script without realizing it, which explains a lot; rather embarrassing, and a good lesson to double-check my console inputs while testing.  I will mark this as closed, my code seems to work now that I'm running the right code...sorry for my dumb error, and thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @CR No worries, the question was well written. Goodluck!

Comment: Just noting here that I updated my question's code slightly after AShelly pointed out my syntax errors.  It works now, it helps a lot to run the correct script in the first place!

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book. Also be aware that Python 2 will reach its End Of Life in 2020, so you really ought to be learning Python 3, unless you _need_ Python 2 to work on legacy code.

Comment: @PM-2Ring Thanks for the warning, I will look at those other examples listed and bear those critiques in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure why this is failing, but in my guess the more pythonic way of doing this is via a try except statement to catch a value error:

```
try:
    #The following will fail with an non-numeric input
    how_much = int(choice)
except ValueError:
    dead('Man, learn to type a number.')
#Note that the else statement is not necessary as it will never execute anyway
```

Comment: Thanks; my actual problem proved to be unrelated to the code I was attempting to test in the end, but this is a helpful improvement over what I was doing regardless. =)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make dead function in your script

```
def dead(message):
    print(message)
choice = raw_input("> ")
print "test"
if choice.isdigit() == False:
    dead("Man learn to type a number")
```

Comment: The "dead()" function is provided and working elsewhere in the script I am using, I was just trying to highlight the function which seemed to be throwing the error.  Thanks though.

Comment: hello don't use simple spaces after if choice.isdigit() == False:

Comment: use space with 'tab' button and don't forget :':'