# Python: find top-level folders that have only digits in names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find top-level folders that have only digits in names. F.e. we have such folder structure

```
.
├── Folder1
|   ├── some.file
├── 111
|   ├── some.folder
|   ├── some.file
|   ├── some.file
|   ├── some.file-2
├── 555
|   ├── some.folder
|   ├── some.file
```

Expected results: found folders '111' and '555'

Here is my code:

```
import os

main_path = 'C:\\Users'
top_folders_list = next(os.walk(main_path))[1]
condition = '111'
if condition in top_folders_list:
   ...do_something...
```

Code works but (of cource) only for folder '111'. Which condition should I use for matching '111', '555' and all other top-level folders that have only digits in names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check in python whether a string contains only numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388541/how-do-you-check-in-python-whether-a-string-contains-only-numbers)

Comment: You can use [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isnumeric()` on string object

```
for fold in fold_lst:
    if fold.isnumeric():
        print(fold)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to filter the condition:

## "\d" stands for only numeric.

```
import re

folders = ("123451","8971231")
for folder in folders:
  x = re.findall("\\d", folder)
  result = "".join(x)
  print(result)
```

And that should give you the desired effect.

Comment: Well, thanks. Solution above is simplier but your solution is more powerfull. F.e. for code uniformity (find not only folders with digits but also contains only letters etc)